# Chrome file download name incorrect

Tags: html, google-chrome

I have the following line 
`<a id="export" href="data:text/plain;base64,MDow" download="fname">Download</a>`

I'd expect this to save a file as `fname.txt`, however, Chrome always saves it as `download.txt`. Tested this on firefox, it gives the expected behavior `fname.txt`.

[This](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=375634) suggests that this behavior is intentional and won't be fixed, so my question is, is there a way to download it with the correct filename?

Comment: First thing you need to do is use a space between the double quote and  the `download` attribute

Comment: @Mr.Alien Sorry, the space is there, mistake in simplfying.

Comment: If you change it to download="fname.txt" does it affect anything?

Comment: Why do you have `data:text/plain;base64`?

Comment: @wbt11a No, still as download.txt

Comment: @j08691 it means that the text file body is embedded in the html. in his case, his text is "MDow" which means '0:0'

Answer (score 2):

It's not just a security concern

the pseudo specification says:

> The attribute can furthermore be given a value, to specify the file
> name that user agents are to use when storing the resource in a file
> system. This value can be overridden by the Content-Disposition HTTP
> header's filename parameters. [RFC6266] In cross-origin situations,
> the download attribute has to be combined with the Content-Disposition
> HTTP header, specifically with the attachment disposition type, to
> avoid the user being warned of possibly nefarious activity. (This is
> to protect users from being made to download sensitive personal or
> confidential information without their full understanding.)

Sure if the browser detects a header which go against yours, will not use your definition.

## **Which is not your case...**

You have a bad formated base64 text:

this should work.

```
<a id="export" href="data:text/plain;base64,MDow" download="fname.txt"> Download</a>
```

And try a diferent encoding if you need a expanded charset than utf-8, use iso-8859-1 insted

example 2

```
<a download="fname" href="data:image/jpeg;base64,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" >image code</a>
```

Note: My ".txt" extension at download attribute is not necessary but it is good practice

Edit2: TEsted in 37.0.2058.2

fidle:
http://jsfiddle.net/yL8UZ/

Comment: I'm at canary. which is 37.0.2058.2. what is your version?

Comment: 35.0.1916.153, latest stable

Comment: tested it at  34.0.1847.137 m , and worked.. even downloaded with my name atribute using a cross-origin  and Content-Disposition  header ( its should  override  my name , so is a bug)

Comment: They all download as download.*

Comment: then is  your chrome version. at v34 it download everything without override. at v37 it overrides a cross-domain or content-disposition in other case uses the download attribute content as name,

Comment: so my question is, is there a way to download it with the correct filename? A:not at your chrome version. since i didn't test at v35 and my fiddle exposes what I test. chrome version or extension are doing something else. at least test with incognito.